# Simple image and audio upload being blocked firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am making a music streaming app and I am able to retrieve data from the database to play a song and display the metadata but when I try to upload a song from my emulator it says I do not have permission. My rules are defined as public and I have connected my app to firebase. I even generated a SHA-1 key for the app and synced it to firebase but am stuck with the same error. Do I need to include authentication to remotely upload? Any help is appreciated

[image: Here is the code for uploading the picture]
[here are the rules for my firebase storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuMmA.png)

[image: Here is the error]

Comment: Show us the rules that you are using.

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /b/com.cnu.soundify.appspot.com/o {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}

Comment: Show us the rules that you are using for Cloud Storage.